# AngularJS - Use ng-style to set color of radio button label when checked

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-style

I know how to set the color of a radio button label with `ng-style`, like this:

```
ng-style="{'background-color': buttonColor}"
```

But how can I change the color of the radio button label when it is checked using the `ng-style` directive?  In css it is like this:

```
.radio-button:checked+label {
    background-color: #52b6db;
    border: 1px solid #52b6db;
}
```

**EDIT:** Basically, how do I tap into the `:checked+label` style property through `ng-style`?

Comment: Could you post a codepen?

Comment: you can use ng-class as well..

Comment: ngstyle uses inline style so it is not possible. Use ng-class instead

Answer (score 0):

Basically call a function in your controller for ng-style and return the appropriate style object based on the value of the button.

```
ng-style="$ctrl.getStyle()"

function getStyle() {
if (some condition) {
    return {
        background-color: #52b6db;
        border: 1px solid #52b6db;
} else {
    return {...}
}
```

OK, this is a little bit out there, but you can do this. If on your index.html page you've loaded your app at the document level (on the html tag), you can actually have a  section with a controller on it and define css using controller references, so you could dynamically set colors for radio-button:checked+label this way.

Comment: I am wondering tho how to tap into the `:checked+label` style property through `ng-style`?

Comment: I don't think you need ng-style at all for this. It seems like something that you should just be able to do with straight css. I wouldn't try to mix ng-style with css classes. Seems like just going with ng-class would be much more straightforward.

Comment: but the thing is that with straight css classes I cannot make the color dynamic, whereas with `ng-style` I can

Comment: OK. Not sure you can tie into :checked+label there, but using a controller method should give you the same result.

Comment: Updated the answer. I did something like this on an app before I started using Angular Material.